# 'nothing to be done for' error with .PHONY rule

Tags: makefile

I have a wildcard rule to grab all of the files in a directory as tests and run them, and a .PHONY rule to make sure I can run all of the tests regardless of whether they've been previously run. When I run `make tests/PA5obj.java` or `make test` it returns with `make: Nothing to be done for 'test'.

Sometimes after I add new files to the `tests/` dir, I have to run `make clean` before it will pick them up in `make test`, so I'm unsure if there's a caching issue or something, but that wouldn't explain why `make test` is also not working.

Here is the relevant section of the makefile:

```
PROG = Test
TESTS = $(wildcard tests/*.java)

.SUFFIXES: .java.class

#-------------------------
JCC = javac
JAR = jar
#-------------------------

all: $(PROG).jar

.PHONY:test $(TESTS)
test: $(TESTS)

tests/%.java: $(PROG).jar
    @echo "#### testing $@ ####"
    @java -jar $(PROG).jar $@
    @echo "> Passed"

$(PROG).jar: Main.class
    $(JAR) cmf $(PROG)MainClass.txt $(PROG).jar $^

Main.class: Main.java
    javac $^
```

The necessary files are:

TestMainClass.txt

```
Main-Class: Main
```

and Main.java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.System;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

class Main {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    if (args.length < 1) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Usage: Main <filename> ");
    }
    String filename = args[args.length-1];
    try {
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(filename));
      System.out.println("Contents of file: " + filename);
      while (sc.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
      }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      System.out.println(e);
      System.exit(1);
    }
  }
}
```

Running `make test` should simply read all of the files in the `test` dir (as a minimal example)

Comment: What is `PROG`, and how old is `$(PROG).jar`?

Comment: $(PROG) is the actual target program. It needs to exist to run the tests. $(PROG).jar is removed when I run `make clean`, but the test rules still don't work

Comment: Without a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I don't think we can help you.

Comment: Added a simplified example

Answer (score 4):

Make will execute the rule of a `PHONY` target, even if a file exists with that name.

**But** this does not apply to pattern rules, which is why you have this problem.

***But*** it *does* apply to *static* pattern rules (at least in the version of GNU Make I'm using). So give this a try:

```
$(TESTS): tests/%.java: $(PROG).jar
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any targets that depend on the test target. Since the test target depends on the jar target, you can change the all target to depend on the test target instead of the jar target.